# trigger azure data factory pipeline from azure function

Tags: azure-functions

how to trigger a  azure data factory pipeline from azure function using the  visual studio code? i am getting below error while running visual studio code to trigger pipeline.
"Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory, Version=5.2.9.0, Culture=neutral"

I have already installed this package, but still am getting this exception. Can anyone help on this.

Comment: What is the SDK version?

Comment: this issue has solved after moving to VS2019 from VS2017